# automatically call all method inside the class in php

Tags: php, oop, class, methods

Is there a way to call all the methods from a class once the class is initialized? For example, lets say I have a class named `todo` and once I make an instance of a `todo` class, all the methods/functions inside it will be executed, without calling it in the  constructor?

```
<?php 
    class todo 
    {
        function a()
        {
        }
        function b()
        {
        }
        function c()
        {
        }
        function d()
        {
        }
    }

    $todo = new todo();
?>
```

In here I created an instance of a class `todo` so that the methods `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` will be executed. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible - you use constructor to achieve that. why you don't want to use constructor?

Comment: ah ok, i just wondering if theres anyway, i just dont want to call every function of it, let say i have a 100 function?

Comment: If you're dead set against calling all methods in the constructor, there's also [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Comment: you can play with `get_class_methods($this)` but its not recommended, since in production uses methods will require parameters (or maybe not)

Answer (score 6):

This outputs 'abc'.

```
class Testing
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods($this);

        forEach($methods as $method)
        {
            if($method != '__construct')
            {
                echo $this->{$method}();
            }
        }
    }

    public function a()
    {
        return 'a';
    }

    public function b()
    {
        return 'b';
    }

    public function c()
    {
        return 'c';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use iterator. All methods will be called in foreach  [PHP Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `__construct()` method (as you mentioned), which is called on object instantiation. Anything else would be unfamiliar and unexpected (to have random methods instantly executed not by the constructor).

Your class code looks like you're using PHP4, if that's the case, name your constructor the same as the class name.

Comment: If that's the case, he should update his PHP server. C'mon, it's 2007 already.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? I use this pattern to register meta data about classes sometimes.

```
<?php
class todo {
    public static function init() {
        self::a();
        self::b();
        self::c();
        self::d();
    }
    function a()
    {
    }
    function b()
    {
    }
    function c()
    {
    }
    function d()
    {
    }
}

todo::init();
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way that I can think of, short of putting it into the constructor as you suggest in your question:

```
<?php 
    class todo 
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->a();
            $this->b();
            $this->c();
            $this->d();
        }
        function a()
        {
        }
        function b()
        {
        }
        function c()
        {
        }
        function d()
        {
        }
    }

    $todo = new todo();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted below class from php.net...

I thought it will be usefull because methods are not called using objects, instead using get_class_methods():

```
class myclass {
    function myclass()
    {
        return(truenter code heree);
    }

    function myfunc1()
    {
        return(true);
    }

    function myfunc2()
    {
        return(true);
    }
}

$class_methods = get_class_methods('myclass');
foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {
    echo "$method_name\n";
}
```